# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging raises errors in Release but not in Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got a ClickOnce project I've just updated from VS2010 to VS2015 that has a reference to the above in it (eg Using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;).

When I run the project in Debug, it doesn't flag that reference or it's uses at all.

When I swap to Release, the Using statement is flagged saying  "Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I've tried to install the Enteprise Logging library from NuGet but it fails saying it doesn't target .Net 4 (the targeted framework hasn't been changed by me between updating VS versions)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BlahBalh.BudgetReporting.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the writing of information to the log (Event Viewer).
    /// Uses the Microsoft Best Practices Library, see App.config for loggin options.
    /// </summary>
    public class Log
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor - private as this is a static class
        /// </summary>
        private Log() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add the information to the log.
        /// Use for general information messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Title">Message Heading</param>
        /// <param name="Message">Detailed information.</param>
        public static void LogInformation(string Title, string Message)
        {
            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
            logEntry.Title = Title;
            logEntry.Message = Message;
            logEntry.Priority = 0;
            logEntry.EventId = 1;
            logEntry.Severity = TraceEventType.Information;
            logEntry.Categories.Add("General");
            WriteEntry(logEntry);
        }
```

etc...

I've also tried to find the Assembly reference area but can't see it in VS2015 (has it been replaced by NuGet?)

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can see Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging in my References list, and the .dll is visible when I look at the project files in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Also, if I move to a new line in the Using's section and type 'Using Microsoft' Intellisense is only giving me CSharp, Office, SqlServer, VisualBasic and Win32, no Practices; does that mean the reference isn't working properly?

Comment: Also, when I select the reference, the properties pane is saying Resolved = True

Comment: I m having the same issue, If anybody has the solution for this. Please let me know.